# Recommendation for Compiling C++ Static Library for Different OSs?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost

Let's say I use CentOS 7 and GCC 7 to compile a static library (let's call it mylib.a) and I would like to use it (compiled against) on CentOS 6 (with older system libraries).

What's the best way to do so?  Static linking to libstdc++, etc?  What else?

Currently, I am getting something like this when I built (with gcc 4.x on CentOS 6) an executable against my static library mylib.a:

```
/opt/boost/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp:62: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
mylib.a([myFile].o): In function `std::locale::locale<boost::date_time::date_facet<boost::gregorian::date, char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(std::locale const&, boost::date_time::date_facet<boost::gregorian::date, char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >*)':
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_classes.tcc:47: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
```

I suspect that it is because boost_date_time.a wasn't built against libstdc++.a when it was built with gcc 4.x on CentOS 7 without the latest dev tool.

Thought?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about the actual static library, or application which uses the static library? If the first, how about providing separate static library files for different targets?

Comment: The error above appears when I build my executable against mylib.a built on a different OS.

Comment: @hyde I am not a build guy so I am not sure how to setup multiple targets for different systems.  It sounds like I need to have multiple VMs?  My requirement is kind of simple -- building mylib.a with gcc 7 + centos 7 and then building the executable with gcc 4.x + centos 6 and running there.

Comment: No you do not need VMs, you just need different toolchains

Comment: cross-compile it.

Comment: in debian there is a tool called `sbuild`. It allows creating `chroot` environments of different debian/ubuntu etc. versions and then it allows building inside of those environments. I assume there is something similar for redhat based distros... Or you can create needed chroot envs by hand and build inside of those.

Comment: @igagis I will look into it.  thanks for your suggestion.  I am curious if mylib.a has already linked to all the related static libraries and so my static library should be able to run an older version of OS/lib etc.  No?

Comment: @RichardHodges I took a quick look at cross compiler.  Seems like people uses it for building binaries for a different architecture.  But in my case, both host (build) and target machines are x86_64.  I wonder how cross compiler helps in this case.  Any pointer?  Thanks!

Comment: It seems like another use case for cross compiler is that it can target a different libc.  Maybe this is necessary for my case as the CentOS 6 machine has a different libc for sure.  Let me give it a try.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Build on the oldest supported system - that way it usually works on Linux. Newer versions of gcc and libstdc++ is usually compatible with older ones.

Comment: Ha, right, unfortunately, I would like to do the reverse -- building on the newer system and using on the older system.  No way to get it work.  I know this request sounds insane.  But I was hoping that the existence of static libraries can fulfill the request somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with [Musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/), the static linked c library, then build your program with all static libraries include libc and libstdc++, it's a universal Linux executable program.

The Alpine disto has shipped Musl as the default libc library, so I suggest you use a docker image with alpine to build your program with CI/CD pipeline.

But be aware there are some trivial differences between glibc and musl, you may need to change your program to make it musl compatible